# Send notification to Mountain lion notification center

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

Can someone give an example of sending a test notification from a Cocoa app to Notifications Center? eg. when I click on an `NSButton`

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Notifications in Mountain Lion are handled by two classes. `NSUserNotification` and `NSUserNotificationCenter`. `NSUserNotification` is your actual notification, it has a title, a message etc. that can be set via properties. To deliver a notification that you've created, you can use the `deliverNotification:` method available in NSUserNotificationCenter. The Apple docs have detailed information on [NSUserNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) & [NSUserNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but the basic code to post a notification looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)showNotification:(id)sender{
    NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
    notification.title = @"Hello, World!";
    notification.informativeText = @"A notification";
    notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];
    [notification release];
}
```

That'll produce a notification with a title, a message and that'll play the default sound when it's displayed. There's a lot more that you can do with notifications than just this (such as scheduling notifications) and that's all detailed in the documentation I linked to.

One small point, notifications will only be displayed when your application is the key application. If you want your notifications to display regardless of if your application is key or not, you'll need to specify a delegate for `NSUserNotificationCenter` and override the delegate method `userNotificationCenter:shouldPresentNotification:` so that it returns YES. The documentation for `NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate)

Here's an example of providing a delegate to NSUserNotificationCenter and then forcing notifications to be displayed regardless of if your application is key. In your application's AppDelegate.m file, edit it like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
}

- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification{
    return YES;
}
```

And in AppDelegate.h, declare that the class conforms to the NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to override userNotificationCenter? (sorry im really new to this :) )

Comment: @haseo98 Yup, I've just added an example to my answer.

Comment: Im getting an error next to the applicationdidfinishlaunching section of the method, Sending 'AppDelegate *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate>'. Any ideas?

Comment: @haseo98 Whoops, forgot to mention that you need to declare that your AppDelegate conforms to the NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was really stuck on how to make it display a notification while the app is in the foreground and this explained it. Still not sure if I want to use that functionality in my app but at least I know how now!

Comment: What parts of this are different for iOS?

Comment: @alexjohnj I know this is an old answer, but can you elaborate in which scenarios application won't be a key application? Like if it were only a background application it wouldn't be key?

Answer (score 0):

@alexjohnj's answer updated for Swift 5.2

In AppDelegate

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

  // Set delegate
  NSUserNotificationCenter.default.delegate = self
}
```

And then confirm to NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate as

```
extension AppDelegate: NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresent notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
    true
}}
```