# Cocoa: Forcing an NSUserNotification while app is frontmost

Tags: cocoa, delegates, nsusernotification

Fairly straightforward, I have an app that should send a notification but it will not do so if the application is frontmost. From the NSUserNotificationCenter class reference:

> The user notification center reserves the right to decide if a
>   delivered user 
>       notification is presented to the user. For example, it may suppress the 
>       notification if the application is already frontmost (the delegate can override 
>       this action).

From what I can gather it has to do with the `userNotificationCenter:shouldPresentNotification:` method that is shown in the NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol reference but I can't figure out how to implement it. I already set my class to be the NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate so that's not it.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
In the class I set as the NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate I use this to try to override the original method, which defaults as NO if the app is frontmost:

```
- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification {
return YES;
}
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: After looking around some more I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814903/send-notification-to-mountain-lion-notification-center

Answer (score 5):

NSUserNotificationCenter *center = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
[center scheduleNotification:notification];
center.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification
  {return YES;}