# Getting notification list from OS X Notification Center

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks

It's possible to [send notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814903/send-notification-to-mountain-lion-notification-center) to the Notification Center on Mac using [NSUserNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSUserNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API classes.

---

But is there **any** way of reading the notifications from the Notification Center?

Comment: For clarification, though, it's super straightforward to read user notifications you own/scheduled. Other notifications, though, are a problem.

Comment: You are right pointing this out. I didn't mention that I need to get *any* notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Daij-Djan's answer, I could figure out that the preferences for the notification center are located in a SQLite database in `~/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter/`.

To read this database, we can use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) which you will find as a [pod](http://cocoapods.org/).

```
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "FMDatabaseAdditions.h"
```

Get the DB file and open it.

```
NSString *pathToNCSupport = [@"~/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter/" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathToNCSupport error:&error];    //find the db

FMDatabase *database = nil;
for (NSString *child in contents) {
    if([child.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"db"]) {
        database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[pathToNCSupport stringByAppendingPathComponent:child]];
        if([database open]) {
            printf("Opening Notification Center");
            [database close];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Launch any SQL query:

```
if([database open]) {
    FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:@"select count(*) as cnt from presented_notifications"];
    while ([rs next]) {
        int cnt = [rs intForColumn:@"cnt"];
        NSLog(@"Total Records :%d", cnt);
    }

    [database close];
}
```

Complete project on [Github](https://github.com/stephanebruckert/SBNotificationReader).

Comment: Does this approach still work in 2020? If not, is there a way to do this now ?

Comment: This folder does not exists in the Ventura. I guess it's not valid anymore.

Comment: I got it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754189/new-location-of-the-notification-center-db-file-in-10-10

Answer (score 6):

**There is no public API for that. So nothing App Store conform.**

BUT

As part of my little tech-demo-app DiscoNotifier (where I flash the keyboard LEDs in response to a notification) I wrote a DDUserNotificationCenterMonitor class

see: https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DiscoNotifier/tree/master/DiscoNotifier

it works using FileSystemEvents and SQLite and checks the notification center's database

**It works and the database has all info (table: presented_notifications) but.. this is fragile AND private**