# Displaying notifications on OS X

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, uilocalnotification, xcode6, nsnotificationcenter

I'm creating a really simple menu bar app. What I want is this app sending a notification every 20 minutes since it is launched. The thing is, I really haven't found any clear information anywhere on how to display notifications in OS X... Can you help me understand the way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send notification to Mountain lion notification center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814903/send-notification-to-mountain-lion-notification-center)

Answer (score 0):

You should google for NSUserNotification. 
Especially search the Apple developer site. 
That will get you started and point you to sample code. 
WWDC videos tend to be very informative on this.