# Replicate XCode's Build succeeded/failed notification

Tags: objective-c, xcode, notifications

When you build a project in XCode this image pops up which is actually just a png file I believe that says build succeeded or build failed. Does anyone have any idea how I can replicate this type of popup temporary notification using an image like Apple did?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are looking for is ["`NSUserNotification`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [here is a quickstart tutorial on it](http://cocoathings.blogspot.com/2013/01/introduction-to-user-notifications-in.html).

[And a related question with useful answers, to boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814903/send-notification-to-mountain-lion-notification-center).