# Why doesn't this pyside window disappear?

Tags: python, qt, notifications, pyside

I am looking for a way to do cross-platform notification, here is some code from [Cross-platform desktop notifier in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240674/cross-platform-desktop-notifier-in-python) , with some modification to make it runable:

```
# uiToast.py
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(547, 96)
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        MainWindow.setPalette(palette)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.display = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.display.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 551, 101))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 170, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        self.display.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.display.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, time
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import uiToast

window = None   # global

# Usage: Toast('Message')
class Toast(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        global window               # some space outside the local stack
        window = self               # save pointer till killed to avoid GC
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.ui = uiToast.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.display.setText(msg)

        self.toastThread = ToastThread()    # start thread to remove display
        self.connect(self.toastThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("finished()"), self.toastDone)
        self.toastThread.start()
        self.show()

    def toastDone(self):
        global window
        window = None               # kill pointer to window object to close it and GC

class ToastThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(2.0)             # wait and die



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    program = Toast("hi")
    program.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is the pop up window, which is supposed to disappear in 2 seconds, is hanging forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window isn't "hanging" - it's just that the code that attempts to close the window is pure nonsense.

Setting `window` to `None` will not delete the object, because it was assigned to the name `program` when it was created, and that reference will continue to exist after the `toastDone` method is called.

What you should do instead is just connect the thread's `finished` signal to the window's `close` slot. Try something like this:

```
class Toast(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.ui = uiToast.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.display.setText(msg)
        self.toastThread = ToastThread()
        self.toastThread.finished.connect(self.close)
        self.toastThread.start()

class ToastThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(2.0)
```