# Webcrawling using Scrapy : alert when keyword spoted in forum

Tags: python, search, web-crawler, scrapy, forum

a few months back, I started my search for some easy way to write a script that could alert me when a keyword is posted in a thread from a forum section.

So, my research leads me to the python module scrapy, that I was happy to try because I already knew some python.

I tried but the result I got was not satisfactory enough.

let's explain what i wanted:

I am interested in retrieving the threads from the forum classified section, check if a new message has been posted and send me a message if a new thread with a specific word appears in the title.

Here is my code, ntspider.py:

```
from scrapy.http import Request

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "LP195xSearch"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mylespaul.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mylespaul.com/forums/member-classifieds/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//a[contains(@id,"thread_title")]/text()').extract()
        t =[]

        for title in titles:
            t.append(title)
            item = LP195xSearchItem()
            item["title"] = title
            yield item

        for i in xrange(len(t)):
            print repr(str(t[i])).center(20)
```

This is only retrieving and printing the threads titles, and now I want to allert me if onw keywork is found.

Any help would be very very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

you don't really need scrapy for this, but for notifications I think you need to create something like the following:

1. Setup a cron job to execute your spider periodically (daily, hourly, what you want).
2. Setup a database where to drop your thread items.
3. When getting an item, check if it isn't already on your database and if the title contains your `keyword` and send a notification (you can check alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240674/cross-platform-desktop-notifier-in-python) or an email that is your choice).

I say that you don't really need scrapy here, because you just need to read plain text on a page which can be done inside a simple script with the `requests` library or one of your choice.

Comment: OK thanks, that is the kind of information I am looking for too... I had a quick look at the module requests, and it is satisfying to import the html page, but could you give me an advice on where to start if I want to get say Thread titles from the mega table?

Comment: you can still use selectors, for that, check `parsel` readme https://github.com/scrapy/parsel