# opencv creat an input text box in a GUI and read it

Tags: c++, user-interface, textbox, opencv3.0, editbox

Just wondering if there is any command in OpenCV to create an input "Text box" or"Edit text box" for a GUI in C++? Like name box (to enter a name)

PS: I'm using Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: By the way, there is a nice lightweight (header-only) UI toolkit for OpenCV: https://github.com/Dovyski/cvui

But it does **not** provide text input (see [this](https://github.com/Dovyski/cvui/issues/103)) which is why I ended up here, looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Miki says, there is no such facility in OpenCV itself, but there is nothing to stop you using **Zenity** or any of the alternatives, which work  like this at the command line:

```
zenity  --title  "Gimme some text!" --entry --text "Enter your text here"
```

[image]

If it does what you want, you can integrate it into your C++ program by calling it through `popen()`.

Comment: That is very nice. Can you suggest something similar for Windows?

Comment: I try to avoid Windows, but there are some ideas here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1663944/2836621

Comment: Thanks a lot @Miki and @Mark!

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

---

From the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/highgui.html):

> While OpenCV was designed for use in full-scale applications and can be used within functionally rich UI frameworks (such as Qt*, WinForms*, or Cocoa*) or without any UI at all, sometimes there it is required to try functionality quickly and visualize the results. This is what the HighGUI module has been designed for.

HighGui provides only a limited GUI, mainly for debugging purposes. If you need something more than:

- showing images
- detecting mouse clicks
- using sliders to change some value
- draw shapes or text
- use a button (Qt backend only)

then you need to use some GUI library such as Qt*, WinForms*, or Cocoa*.