# How can I create simple interactive GUI for c++ OpenCV application?

Tags: c++, user-interface, opencv

I am working on object detection application using OpenCV 3.0 with C++. For a presentation, I need simple GUI to choose relevant files, send them to functions, and print out results. In other words, same thing I do in a terminal. I can't find proper way to create this kind of GUI in neither c++ nor OpenCV documentation.

Comment: If you want to do something more than display some image and adjust values using sliders, [you should consider using some GUI library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34695286/5008845) such as Qt.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something really simple, you could use **Zenity**, or one of its alternatives. Try it from the command line like this:

```
zenity  --title="Select an image" --file-selection --multiple
```

[image]

If it fits the bill for your needs, you can integrate it into your C++ program using `popen()` to execute it and then read the filename(s) it outputs.

Note that you can also use it to get arbitrary text or allow section from a list box.

In case anyone else wants to do similar things, but on Apple OSX, you could look at [Cocoa Dialog](https://mstratman.github.io/cocoadialog/).

Comment: This probably does not answer the question. I believe `zenity` does not fill the bill, and if it did, you probably need to use `popen`, not `system`

Comment: Thank you for your comment about `popen()` versus `system()` - I will update the suggestion accordingly. I think it answers the question very well - it is an extremely simple, easy-to-use function that allows the user to select some files without going to the complexity of creating a full-blown `Qt` type of application and the associated steep learning curve. I think a down-vote is a little harsh!