# build a gui with qt for an opencv program

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

i've developed an opencv program, i take some folder path from input so i decided to create a gui with qt. The gui is simple, basically it's some button.
The problem is that i cannot pass the string from a button to another.

```
std::string MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    QString salvataggi=QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(
                this,
                tr("Open File"),
                "/home/"
                );
    salvat= salvataggi.toStdString();
    return salvat;
}
```

I tried to use the pointers but without any resoult.

```
std::string MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    QString salvataggi=QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(
                this,
                tr("Open File"),
                "/home/"
                );
    savee= &salvat;
    *savee = salvataggi.toStdString();
    return savee;
}
```

can you tell where i'm wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Using Qt to pass a folder to a program seems an overkill. Just use command line arguments (OpenCV 3 has a nice CommandLineParser), or something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35266625/5008845)

Answer (score 1):

This method is a callback and must return `void`. It is called from the main loop, handled by the Qt engine; and it does not care about the return of the callback.

If you want to store some string from the callback methods, just add some member variable in your `MainWindow` class :

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    // ...
    std::string my_string;
    //...
};
```

And give it the value you want from your callback.

If you only want this info from the user, quit the window: `this->close();` and then get the string from the MainWindow object :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow win;
    win.show();
    a.exec();
    /* do what you want with win.my_string */
    //...
}
```